# How to handle "duplicate error" in Mongo BulkInsert retry

Tags: mongodb, bulkinsert, on-duplicate-key

I'm inserting a large number of documents to a Mongo DB using bulkWrite operation (Java Driver 3.12). I have also implemented a retry mechanism in case of connection disruption.

But there is an issue in the subsequent retries: As some documents have been inserted in previous try, the subsequent try result in `Duplicate Key error`

```java
    @Autorwire  
    private ReactiveMongoOperations operations
    operations
        .execute(Document.class, collection ->
 collection.bulkWrite(insertOneRequests, new BulkWriteOptions().ordered(false)
        .bypassDocumentValidation(true)))
        .retryWhen(Retry.any().fixedBackoff(Duration.ofMillis(backoffDuration)).retryMax(retryCount)
        .doOnRetry(retryContext -> log.info("Retry"));
```

Is there a way to ignore the "Duplicate Key Error" in subsequent retries ?

Given it is not an uncommon scenario, how is normally handled ? Assuming that I'm trying to avoid using "Upsert"(Replace) operations in this case.

Comment: The database is informing you that some of the data you are inserting is duplicating existing data, which is expected behavior. When you insert new data is this data inserted?

Comment: @Oleg: Yes, the database behaves correctly. Let's say I have 100 documents to be inserted, and during the bulkinsert operation, assume some connection issue occurs when only 60 are inserted. Now, the retry kicks in (which is a behaviour of Spring Reactive Mongo as shown in the code). But it does "retry" 100 documents all over again, hence the duplicate key error. My question is that can we configure the bulk write or any flag to set to ignore the "duplicate key error" in subsequent retry ?

Comment: You say it retries the 100 documents, so after 60 errors I assume it'll insert the remaining 40 documents. What is the issue?

Comment: @Oleg: The issue is once it hits a duplicated key error, it immediately returns a BulkWriteError, meaning that bulk insert is a failed retry. In the above example, all the subsequent retries would fail at the first insert, until it hits the retry threshold (3~5).

Comment: Bulk write in unordered mode executes all operations, per https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/driver/tutorials/bulk-writes/. What are you asking exactly?

Comment: @Oleg: Turned out I misunderstood how bulkwrite works. It attempted all operations. My assumption was that the bulk operation stops once it hits an error in any operation. Anyway, all good now. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Both behaviors are possible. In ordered mode the write will stop at the first error, in unordered mode all operations will be attempted.

Answer (score 0):

From this:

"The bulk operation tries to insert every document you had supplied to insert. If the document already exists in the collection, the document is not inserted (because of the duplicate key error), and the next document’s insert operation will be attempted. Note that the insert will be attempted on all the documents supplied."

MongoDB bulkwrite operation already does what I'm expecting. Just need to suppress the "Duplicate Key Error" in my reporting.